# set different colums size and number for each different row in plotly graph object subplots

Tags: python, row, col, plotly.graph-objects

I wonder if is possible to make a sublot with different columns size and number per each row USING PLOTLY.GRAPH_OBJECTS and PLOTLY.SUBPLOTS. like the photoes (sry for the hand made).

[**img 1** row 1 has 2 cols, row 2 has 4 cols: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6XVm.jpg)]

[**img 2** row 1 has 3 cols, 2 of the same width and 1 of different width, row 2 has 4 cols egual to col 3 of row: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2efPQ.jpg)]

it is everything a lot cofused but I hope that you all understand and could give me an answear.

I can set different cols size but this must be egual for each row. I would need different set per row.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible.

For example here, shape gives 4 columns and row, and loc identify the position of each ax.

Colspan allow you to make a plot of 1 column or 2 columns.

```
fig, (axe1) = plt.subplots(1,1,  sharex=False, sharey=False)
ax1  = plt.subplot2grid (shape=(4, 4), loc=(0, 0), colspan=1)
ax2  = plt.subplot2grid (shape=(4, 4), loc=(0, 1), colspan=1)
ax3  = plt.subplot2grid (shape=(4, 4), loc=(1, 0), colspan=1)
ax4  = plt.subplot2grid (shape=(4, 4), loc=(1, 1), colspan=1)
```

Comment: this is very helpful, and, thank you. But I would use ploty graph objects. I thik u're using pyplot in this case